# Screen lock password forgotten on Autel MaxiCheck MX808

Tags: lock-screens, password, locked-out

I have an Android device as following:

- Manufacturer: Autel
- Model: MaxiCheck MX808 Automotive scanner tablet
- Firmware Version: 1.0

I forgot the screen lock password.

I communicated with Autel Tech Support on http://www.autel.com/ and they sent me a flash file and steps on how to flash, but I did not succeed. While I started ADB.exe, I got "Error unauthorized device".

So please assist in resolving the issue.

Ok steps I got from the support as follows
MK Format Device Compulsively

##### Set up Computer Circumstances

1. Install RK driver - Open the folder `RK_DriverAssitant`, run Driverintall.exe, following the on-screen prompts to install the driver.
2. Install Google-USB driver Some computers may need to install this driver. Open the folder `Google-USB_driver`; If your computer OS is 32-bit, run `DPInst32.exe` and if your computer OS is 64-bit, run `DPInst64.exe`. If you have already installed this driver before, please go directly to next step.

##### Reflash the Device

Attention：This procedure will format your device and will delete the data on your device.

3. Run Reflashing ToolOpen the folder `AndroidTool_Release_v2.1`, run `AndroidTool.exe`, the reflashing window will be displayed as shown in the figure below.
4. Turn Your Device into Reflashing Mode Connect your device to computer with USB cable and wait until the computer recognizes the device. You can check the connection status via Device Manager on your computer. As it is shown in the red mark on the figure below, the device was already recognized by the computer.
5. Ready to reflash:
   Double click on the script named
   `reboot to loader.bat`

With best regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adb is only used to reboot the device into "reflashing mode". Most likely this mode is bootloader mode. Usually you can get into bootloader mode by holding the volume down hardware key while booting. But I guess, that that Autel device has no volume hardware keys, right?

May be Autel expects the device to be not locked, so you can accept the adb unauthorized dialog.

An alternative way would be that Autel provides the files `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub`. You can try to examine the provided installers if they contain such files. If they exist then Autel has some pre-installed authorized adb keys on the device. Then you only have to copy them into the `.android` directory in the user home folder `C:\Users\%username%\.android`